# Sudo long wait for Active Directory user

Tags: fedora, sudo, authentication, active-directory, sssd

My Fedora 26 (was 25 when installed/joined to AD) has a long timeout when I run `sudo` for my Active Directory user if I leave it alone for to long.

Timeout is long. 25 seconds.

I used `strace` (`sudo strace -tt -o sudo_wait.strace sudo dnf update -y`) to see if I could see what the system was doing for those 25 seconds, but it seem to be nothing:

```
[...]
07:50:48.362655 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
07:50:48.367202 recvfrom(7, "", 8, MSG_WAITALL, NULL, NULL) = 0
07:50:48.367287 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
07:51:12.493581 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29817, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=896, si_stime=124} ---
07:51:12.493646 write(4, "\21", 1)      = 1
07:51:12.493717 rt_sigreturn({mask=[]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
07:51:12.493769 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
07:51:12.493820 read(3, "\21", 1)       = 1
[...]
```

It is probably not good that I use `sudo` to run both `strace` and `dnf` as I don't know which one of them is actually causing the delay.

I joined the machine to AD by using instructions [here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=realmd) (or eerily similar).

If I run `sudo` again directly after waiting the 25 seconds there is no delay, but every morning when I try after not touching the machine for a few hours the delay is back.

How can I figure out what the machine is waiting for?

ow can I tweak how long credentials are cached?

How can I tweak how long the timeout is?

EDIT: Just found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System-Level_Authentication_Guide/troubleshooting-sudo.html) on RedHat. Creating the `/etc/sudo.conf` as suggested did produce a debug log. Now I'll just have to wait for the delay to come back and then go through that log.

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"? Does it _work_, just with a longer-than-desired delay?

Comment: @mattdm yes, it works. But it takes 25 seconds before sudo asks for my password.

Comment: Generally, we use "timeout" to refer to failures.

Comment: But anyway: does it happen for _other_ things (like login, or screensaver unlock) after a few hours?

Comment: No, I think I've only seen the delay with sudo. But after I get the password prompt it works normally.

Comment: Try using `sudo -v` instead of `sudo dnf`, to simplify the problem....

Comment: @mattdm `sudo -v` is for validate, not verbose. It gave no more info, just the same delay.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it removes dnf from the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your AD user a member of many large AD groups? This is typically the case, usually suppressing the group members with the ignore_group_members option helps.

Alternatively, checking the sssd logs if the machine is able to connect to AD DCs and is not e.g. timing out the connection is also a good thing to do.

Comment: The sudo debug log as mentioned above is quite verbose, so I did not understand what was eating the time from reading it before. Going through it after your answer I do see alot of group-stuff going on there.

I added `ignore_group_members = True` to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.